# CPU not waking monitor from sleep (driver issue?)

Tags: display, hdmi, vga, device-manager

My (Windows 11) CPU is not connecting to its monitor, despite all other peripherals working normally. The system itself also works completely normally, I am able to use the keyboard, mouse and speakers completely fine.

I suspect the issue is a driver change I made, where I turned off a setting corresponding to being able to wake up the monitor from sleep mode (device manager), since I have tried resetting BIOS and nothing changed.

Said monitor is an older model, connecting to my PC using a hdmi-vga adapter, and it works fine with other desktops (although the other desktops have vga ports and don’t use the hdmi-vga adapter). My current desktop does not work with any older monitor, and I do not have a hdmi monitor to test.

Is there some way to change / reset device manager settings without the use of a monitor? Failing that, is there a way to connect a monitor to a desktop with this change?